# Is there a way module to tell if you're logged into Dev, Stage, or Production

Tags: 7

Our deployment model has

1. Dev
2. Stage
3. Production
4. Failover (mysql replication and load balancer)

Our problem is that the server has failed over, we want to alert content editors that they're on the failover, or moreso, we'd like to ensure they're editing in the production areas and not on a development box.

Is there a way to distinguish the environment, after a user logs in? Is there a module by which color codes the admin bar depending on the server's host name?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try [Environment Indicator](https://www.drupal.org/project/environment_indicator), it does exactly what you want.

> This module will help you to keep sane while working on your different
>   environments by adding a configurable color bar to each one of your
>   environments.

It also integrates nicely with Admin Menu.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the 1st answer, 
[environment_indicator](https://www.drupal.org/project/environment_indicator) is the one you are looking for.

Well, we also use the same kind of development model and for ease of use if [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module is used then you can have the settings written in a file. This makes the colour changing automated.

Follow the code below, this can be imported via Features module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_default_environment_indicator_environment().
 */
function mymodule_default_environment_indicator_environment() {
  $export = array();

  $environment = new stdClass();
  $environment->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default environment disabled initially */
  $environment->api_version = 1;
  $environment->machine = 'live';
  $environment->name = 'Live';
  $environment->regexurl = 'example.com';
  $environment->settings = array(
    'color' => '#bb0000',
    'text_color' => '#ffffff',
    'weight' => '',
    'position' => 'top',
    'fixed' => 0,
  );
  $export['live'] = $environment;

  $environment = new stdClass();
  $environment->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default environment disabled initially */
  $environment->api_version = 1;
  $environment->machine = 'staging';
  $environment->name = 'Staging';
  $environment->regexurl = 'stage.example.com';
  $environment->settings = array(
    'color' => '#000099',
    'text_color' => '#ffffff',
    'weight' => '',
    'position' => 'top',
    'fixed' => 0,
  );
  $export['staging'] = $environment;

  $environment = new stdClass();
  $environment->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default environment disabled initially */
  $environment->api_version = 1;
  $environment->machine = 'dev';
  $environment->name = 'Dev';
  $environment->regexurl = 'dev.example.com';
  $environment->settings = array(
    'color' => '#000066',
    'text_color' => '#ffffff',
    'weight' => '',
    'position' => 'top',
    'fixed' => 0,
  );
  $export['dev'] = $environment;

  return $export;
}
```

Comment: Selected the module answer but still an up-vote for this. Many, many thanks.